# Swift merge .ts or mpeg files

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, video, avasset

I have an array of local files, I downloaded them from a .m3u8 playlist, since i have to save for later local playing.
All the files are in .ts format, and I want to merge them all in a single video file. I already tried to merge the files using `AVMutableComposition`, I tried to convert all local files to a `AVAsset` but the property `.tracks` always return 0, so i presume the AVAsset was incorrect, then I tried to rename all the files to `MPEG` but the problem still the same.

Does anyone have any idea on how to, read correctly those files, here is my code so far :

```
 func mergeAllVideos(filesPath: URL) {
        let allVideos = extractAllFile(atPath: filesPath.absoluteString)
        var arrayVideos = [AVURLAsset]()
        var atTimeM: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
        var lastAsset: AVAsset!
        var layerInstructionsArray = [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()
        var completeTrackDuration: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
        var videoSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        var totalTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)

        for asset in allVideos.enumerated() {
            if let url = URL(string: asset.element) {

                let newAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
                arrayVideos.append(newAsset)
            }
        }

        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        for videoAsset in arrayVideos {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoAsset.url)

            let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            do {
                if videoAsset == arrayVideos.first{
                    atTimeM = kCMTimeZero
                } else{
                    atTimeM = totalTime
                }
                print(videoAsset.tracks)
                try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: atTimeM)
                videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }

            totalTime = CMTimeAdd(totalTime, videoAsset.duration)

            completeTrackDuration = CMTimeAdd(completeTrackDuration, videoAsset.duration)
            let videoInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
            if let asset = arrayVideos.last, videoAsset != asset {
                videoInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: completeTrackDuration)
            }
            layerInstructionsArray.append(videoInstruction)
            lastAsset = videoAsset
        }

        let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, completeTrackDuration)
        mainInstruction.layerInstructions = layerInstructionsArray

        let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)

        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.developerApplicationDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
        let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)

        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        exporter!.outputURL = url as URL
        exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exporter!.videoComposition = mainComposition
        exporter!.exportAsynchronously { 
            print("exported")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't work with `.ts`files,  also renaming of `.tv` extension to `.mp4` will not be enough

You need to translate `.tv` file to `mp4`. You can use this lib https://github.com/Keemotion/TS2MP4 for this

And then you will be able to mix videos